# Is it possible to have a cv::Mat that contains pointers to scalars rather than scalars?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am attempting to bridge between VTK (3D visualization library) and OpenCV (image processing library).

Currently, I am doing the following:

`vtkWindowToImageFilter` converts `vtkRenderWindow` (scene) into `vtkImageData` (pixels of render window).

I then have to copy each pixel of `vtkImageData` into a `cv::Mat` for processing and display with OpenCV.

This process needs to run in real time, so the redundant copy (scene pixels into `ImageData` into `Mat`) severely impacts performance. I would like to map directly from scene pixels to `cv::Mat`.

As the scene changes, I would like the `cv::Mat` to automatically reference the scene. Essentially, I would like a `cv::Mat<uchar *>`, rather than a `cv::Mat<uchar>`. Does that make sense? Or am I overcomplicating it?

Comment: imho, a `cv::Mat<uchar *>` does not make any sense in opencv. but if you can get some sort of 'pixel-pointer' from vtkImageData , you could construct a Mat from that, like Mat(h,w,type,ptr) and have it updated automatically that way

Comment: Hi @berak, I've used your solution (which is exactly what I wanted, so thank you!) but I've encountered some conversion issues. I've started a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262199/converting-between-vtk-framebuffer-and-opencv-mat-data

Answer (score 1):

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> image = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();

int dims[3];
image->GetImageData()->GetDimensions(dims);
cv::Mat matImage(cv::Size(dims[0], dims[1]), CV_8UC3, image->GetImageData()->GetScalarPointer());`
```

I succeeded implementing `vtkimagedata*` directly into `cv::Mat` pointer array..

some functions such as
 `cv::flip` or `matImage -= cv::Scalar(255,0,0)`

directly working on vtkimagedata.

but functions like `cv::resize` or `cv::Canny` doesn't work.