# Converting between VTK framebuffer and OpenCV Mat data

Tags: c++, opencv, vtk

I am visualizing data in VTK and I want to grab the framebuffer of the renderwindow and show it in an OpenCV application.

I am currently attempting this through:

```
void aig::VirtualScene::Mat(cv::Mat &m) {
  typedef unsigned char pixel;
  pixel *pixels = this->window_->GetRGBACharPixelData(0, 0, this->w_, this->h_, true);
  m = cv::Mat(this->h_, this->w_, CV_8UC4, pixels);
}
```

But I am ending up with a distorted image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4nOxNzJ.png]

(both upside down and slanted, which I assume is a *step* issue.

Is there an obvious error in this code? I know the upside down issue is because of the origin of the two data coordinates. Mostly interested in the slant issue.

Comment: are you sure, the original image is rgba ? (not rgb ?)

Comment: Does it work properly if the width is a power of 2? I don't know about vtk and opencv, but some implementations add "padding" bytes at the end of each row - which might produce that result.

Comment: yea padding is a good hint, too (but this might require you to copy the image row-wise and not just take over a pointer). also, since vtk is more a 3d engine , they might have the image origin at bottom-left, while opencv has it top-left. there's a simple flip() operation in opencv to fix it

Comment: I have not attempting to check the power-of-2, but this is the result if I assume the image is RGB rather than RGBA (also contains the cv::flip(..)):

[http://i.imgur.com/kyt7DhI.png](http://i.imgur.com/kyt7DhI.png)

    void aig::VirtualScene::Mat(cv::Mat &m) {
      typedef unsigned char pixel;
      pixel *pixels = this->window_->GetPixelData(0, 0, this->w_, this->h_, true);
      m = cv::Mat(this->h_, this->w_, CV_8UC3, pixels);
      cv::flip(m, m, 0);
    }

Comment: Looking at the vtk docs it seems that it always returns the pixel in the format you ask for. If you get the pixels via GetRGBACharPixelData you get RGBA, if you call GetPixelData you get RGB, so I would rule that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the definition of `GetRGBACharPixelData`:

```
virtual unsigned char *GetPixelData(int x,int y,int x2,int y2,int front);
```

You can see that it takes *the index of the top-right angle* (x2, y2), not the *size* of the subimage.

Hence what you want is:

```
pixel *pixels = this->window_->GetRGBACharPixelData(0, 0, this->w_ - 1, this->h_ - 1, true);
                                                                   ^^^^         ^^^^
```

Comment: Ah that works perfectly thank you!! I forgot to consider index of corner versus size of rectangle.

Comment: Honestly writing such functions in terms of topleft angle and rectangle size make much more sense, I dont know why vtk decided to implement it this way.

Comment: @adairdavid also notice that although not specified in the vtk documentation (sigh), you are responsible to delete [] the pixel pointer after you used it.

Comment: So it does a copy behind the scenes?

Comment: It calls glReadPixels which copies the data from the host memory (i.e. your GPU) to a buffer allocated with new[] and then returned.