# Rendering VTK visualization using OpenCV instead

Tags: c++, opencv, vtk, oculus

Is it possible to get a rendered frame from a VTK visualization and pass it to OpenCV as an image without actually rendering a VTK window?

Looks like I should be able to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262199/converting-between-vtk-framebuffer-and-opencv-mat-data) to get the rendered VTK frame from a *window* and then pass it to OpenCV code, but I don't want to render the VTK window. (I want to render a PLY mesh using VTK to control the camera pose, then output the rendered view to OpenCV so I can distort it for an Oculus Rift application).

Can I do this using the [vtkRenderer](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderer.html) class and not the [vtkRenderWindow](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderWindow.html) class?

Also, I'm hoping to do this all using the OpenCV VTK module if that is possible.

EDIT: I'm starting to think I should just be doing this with VTK functions alone since there is plenty of attention being paid to VTK and Oculus Rift paired together. I would still prefer to use OpenCV since that side of the code is complete and works nicely already.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can skip the renderwindows since it provides the size of the image.

Comment: The `vtkRenderWindow` is required when rendering by VTK itself. The ´vtkRenderWindow´ creates a OpenGl context to do the drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make your render windows to render offline like this:

`renderWindow->SetOffScreenRendering( 1 );`

Then use a `vtkWindowToImageFilter`:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter> windowToImageFilter = 
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter>::New();
windowToImageFilter->SetInput(renderWindow);
windowToImageFilter->Update();
```

This is called *Offscreen Rendering* in VTK. [Here is a complete example](https://cmake.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/OffScreenRendering)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, haven't tried it yet but this is what I need.

Comment: I guess to link this to OpenCV I need to grab the `windowToImageFilter->GetOutput()` which is type `vtkImageData` and then convert that to OpenCV using something like `cv::Mat openCVImage(dims[0], dims[1], CV_8UC4, image->GetScalarPointer())`. Any comments there?

Comment: I don't know OpenCV, but the VTK part to access the data is the correct way.

Comment: Sorry Brian, I really haven't worked much with OpenCV. So no cmments there. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can render the image offscreen as mentioned by El Marce and then convert the image to OpenCV cv::Mat using

```
unsigned char* Ptr = static_cast<unsigned char*>(windowToImageFilter->GetOutput()->GetScalarPointer(0, 0, 0));

cv::Mat RGBImage(dims[1], dims[0], CV_8UC3, Ptr);
```